# onQueryTextSubmit в SearchView выполняется дважды Android Java

Tags: java, android, search

Привет всем!

Такая проблема, метод `onQueryTextSubmit` в `SearchView` исполняется дважды, а должен всего 1 раз, в чём проблема?

Вот мой код:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (query != null)
                audioRequest(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
if (query != null){
    searchView.clearFocus(); 
    audioRequest(query);
}
    return false;
```

Comment: помогло,спасибо!

Comment: @IgorLobanov пожалуйста=)